# How to return value in nested function React (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition())

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I want to add weather by geolocation into my React+Redux app.
I found that I can get geolocation by this JS method [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, [options])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition). I want to dispatch that to my Redux weatherSlice, but this method returns undefined by default so I can't dispatch it by createAsyncThunk.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const getGeolocation = createAsyncThunk(
  "weather/getGeolocation",
  async () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      /*return */ navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        //  ^^^^^^^^^^ I suggest that I should add return here ,
        // but it's still undefined, because this method return undefined anyway
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        return { latitude, longitude }; // I understand that this won't work
      });
    }
  }
);
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getCurrentPosition method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) probably only works on https or localhost.

The [payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) function of crateAsyncThunk should return a Promise, you can convert a [callback type function to a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api).

In your code it would look like this:

```
export const getGeolocation = createAsyncThunk(
  'weather/getGeolocation',
  () => { // this is the payload creator function
    //return a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      !navigator.geolocation
        ? reject('Geolocation not supported')
        : navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            ({coords:{ latitude, longitude }}) =>
              resolve({ latitude, longitude }),
            reject //reject promise when there is an error
          )
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: It is not working, because Payload Creator get an "undefined"  value, so action object has values like this: `type(pin):"weather/getGeolocation/fulfilled"
payload(pin): {}
requestId(pin):"cG1QJ-iou0lpLE7tonUj4"
requestStatus(pin):"fulfilled"`
I get this action values by Redux DevTools

Comment: @AndriiAntoniuk Could be because position is not an object literal (has prototype but no values) I updated the answer.